# Adding more spaces between "share" and "improve this answer" links

Tags: feature-request

When new users view a post, they get the "*share*" and "*improve this answer*" options. In my opinion the UI can be improved a bit, maybe by  increasing the gap between the two links.

Although it's clear that these are two buttons, it looks like the 4 links are clickable, which is not the case.

[image]

Comment: Shouldn't they be underlined in a way to clarify what is a link and how many there are?

Comment: @Yunnosch: Good idea! But let's also separate _share_ and _improve_ by an underscore.

Comment: Those freehand arrows look acceptable, but I notice a lack of freehand circles.

Comment: It should just say "share improve", in the same way that your question has "share edit close flag" under it. Mixing single words and phrases is what makes it confusing.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont Sorry, fixed.

Comment: Obvious solution is to drop the word "this" so that we have 3 options: "Share" "Improve" "Answer". Interesting that under this question we have Share Edit Flag; what is an Edit Flag and why would I want to Share it?

Comment: @RyanfaeScotland Some have "share edit close delete flag", what is "edit close delete flag"??

Comment: @Maroun "Close" should be interpreted as "Near by", so you share the fact that the close by delete flag was edited